# Laravel - Multiple fileds validation in rules

Tags: validation, laravel, request

i am trying to figure out how to solve this problem... i have a form with 4 inputs : beginDate, beginHour, endDate, endHour. I have an Helper that returns a date object, takes date and hour and mix it up with carbon... now i have got to check that the begin date is minor than the end date... I wanna do this in the request file... any suggestions ? Thx !

```
public function rules()
{
$rules = [
    'beginDate' => 'required|date',
    'beginHour' => 'required',
    'endDate' => 'required|date',
    'endHour' => 'required',
    'user_list' => 'required',
];

$begin = Helper::mergeDateHour($this->beginDate,$this->beginHour);
$end = Helper::mergeDateHour($this->endDate,$this->endHour);

if(!$begin->lt($end)){
    return false;
}

return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can do if you just want to check date.

```
    'endDate' => 'required|date|after:beginDate'
```

If not, You can try using DateTime.
For example,

```
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$test);
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $beginDate = Input::get("beginDate");
        $beginHour = Input::get("beginHour"); // assumming H:i
        $endDate = Input::get("endDate");
        $endHour = Input::get("endHour");            
        $begin = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($beginDate." ".$beginHour.":00")));
        $end = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($endDate." ".$endHour.":00")));

        if($begin > $end)
          echo "1 is faster";//return and say end supposed to be faster
        else
          echo "2 is faster";


    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Please fix the following errors:')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: What if beginDate and endDate are the same but endDate is later than beginDate? I guess he needs to know if the combined date (beginDate+beginHour) is sooner than the combined date (endDate+endHour)

Comment: Exactly my problem is this... i need to know if the combination is greater or less... and i get 4 different parameters incoming from the form...

Comment: Try DateTime and check after the validation?